# Set Tensor Default Shape Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, default, tensor

Folks,

How may I set a default tensor shape? For example, I tried this, but I get a nasty error:

```
      default_batch_size = tf.placeholder_with_default(1, shape=(), \
          name="default_batch_size")
      X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, \
          [default_batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs], name="x_input")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'.
```

Comment: why are you creating a placeholder for your batch size?

Comment: because I need a way to set the default size for the input layer of my graph. I'm trying to find a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Your use of this placeholder is wrong. Consider `placeholder_with_default` as outputting the default value when nothing is fed to it. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# output [1., 1.] if nothing is fed
default = tf.ones([1, 2])

# define the placeholder
input_ = tf.placeholder_with_default(default, shape=[None, 2])

# do something
result = 3 * input_

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # print result when feeding something
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={input_:[[2., 2.]]}))

    # print result when feeding nothing
    print(sess.run(result))
```

You should get this as console output:

```
[[6. 6.]]

[[3. 3.]
 [3. 3.]]
```

When defining a default, its shape has to be consistent with the shape of your placeholder.

Comment: I tried your method, but when I print my frozen graph I still see this (?, n_steps, n_inputs). I cannot get rid of that default question mark (?). So the default size did not stick in the end.

Comment: this is what printed out when I printed my input layer:                                                       Tensor("import/input/x_input:0", shape=(?, 10, 2002), dtype=float32)